Limit type of return type of a function?
I can't understand this code:
type MyFuncType = (a:number) => void

function MyFunc(a:MyFuncType) {
    return a(2)
}

MyFunc((a) => { return 'a'})


I expect TypeScript to prevent me from returning a string in the function, but it allows me to return a string. The expectation is to return void/empty/nothing, not a string
Why won't TypeScript warn me for a wrong type return?

This is because returning something is not incompatible with returning void. Said differently, someone that executes a function of type MyFunc can't use its return value because it is declared to be void. It makes no difference what the function actually returns in this case. It would be totally different would MyFunc be declared as returning a number for example.

There's no true void function in JS, all functions return a value (sometimes that value is undefined). The void type just means "callers should not use the returned value", so it doesn't matter what type that actually is.

undefined is the appropriate return type for this case. See the explanation here.
